# What should be regular expression to replace only two quotes?

Tags: java, regex

```
<element>
  <Argument Name="AWSAccessKeyId" Value="APOEIUVWIE8E78E6"></Argument>
  <Argument Name="SearchIndex" Value="Apparel"></Argument>
  <LegalDisclaimer>Leriya Fashion products,on amazon.in."Leriya Fashion" in search.</LegalDisclaimer>
</element>
```

I want to replace only quotes in this word ("Leriya Fashion").I have tried many regular expression but they replace all the quotes.Right now we know this word but what if we don't know the actual word.

1. `"|[a-z]$$|"$`
2. `"|"+\s`

I want to replace it with blank or space. And the main problem is occurred when we convert this xml to json. Because json take this double quoted as value but in actual its not a value its just a name which is double quoted.So for me its very tough to replace this quote with blank in json thats why I'm trying to replace this in xml file.

Comment: What do you want to replace it with?

Comment: https://regexr.com/ try this and check where it covers the exact regex

Answer (score 3):

If it's only `"Leriya Fashion"`, then why not just use [`String::replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence))

```
str = str.replace("\"Leriya Fashion\"", "Leriya Fashion");
```

I'm assuming you just want to remove the quotes.

Comment: and I want to replace it with just blank or space

Comment: @umang you never mentioned either of these points in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda replaceAll

```
str = Pattern.compile("(.)\"([^\"\r\n]*\"").matcher(str)
    .replaceAll(mr -> mr.group(1).equals("=") ? mr.group()
                      : mr.group(1) + mr.group(2));
```

This will replace all quotes from **any text** `"..."` from non-HTML-attributes (`="..."`).
The dangerous assumption is that quotes only appear in pairs.